# Why no scrollbar appears when my div is outside the body?

Tags: html, css

I've a fixed width `<div>` positionned inside the body element with `float:right`. When I resize the window and the width of the `<div>` is below the width of the window no scrollbar appears.

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div>Some text content inside.</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
   background : blue;
   width      : 400px;
   float      : right;
}
```

It's the same if I change `float:right` by `position:absolute; right:0;`.

If I add `body{overflow:auto;}` it's still the same.

My questions are : Why this behavior? and How can I change it?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sk7Qh/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can never scroll further to the left than the left edge of the document (or further up then the top edge).

Content, however, can be positioned there.

This is what is happening and you can't change it.

The closest you could come would be to set a minimum width on a containing element so that the content is never positioned off the left or top edges.

e.g.

```
body {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 300px;   
}
```

Comment: position:relative is superfluous. isn't it?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni — No, it establishes the body as the positioning context for the absolutely positioned div.

Answer (score 0):

Update after comment from OP:

Then you just use an outside box around your div

```
<div id="outside">
   <div id="inside">
       Text
   </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#outside {
   max-width: 100%;
   overflow-x: auto;
   float: right;
}

#inside {
   background:blue;
   width: 300px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Sk7Qh/6/

Better?

Comment: Ok but my div must have a fixed width. So no max-width is possible.